# Review of hand played with QQ

Tags: texas-hold-em

Second hand of a tournament. Stacks all at 8000 chips.
10 players at table.
Blinds 25/50.  No ante.

**Pre**
Hero BB: 50 with QQ.
MP: Raise to 150.
Button: Raise to 450.
Hero BB: Call.
MP: Call.

**Flop (1,375) J, 10, 5 Rainbow.**
Hero BB: Check
MP: Check
Button: 700
Hero BB: Raise to 1600
MP: Fold
Button: Call

**Turn (4,575) 4 Rainbow.**
Hero BB: 2100
Button: All-in to 5950
Hero BB: Call

Comment: Blinds were 50/25 no ante?

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans correct.

Comment: What did button have?

Answer (score 3):

**Pre**
Second hand in the tournament. You probably don't have any reads. Most weak or lower stakes players are not 3-betting aggressively enough. Especially because of that I agree with you that you don't want to get in 160BB pre-flop without antes. But obviously you have to play queens, so I think calling is by far the best option.

**Flop**
This is in my opinion were you make a big mistake. By check-raising the flop with queens here, you are going to be all-in a lot of the times on the turn or river. Or you will get in super awkward spots out of position. You are super deep and I don't think queens are strong enough. Yes, you might get value from hands like AJ, but I doubt those hand will play for stacks. The button can have AA, KK, JJ, TT, and JTs for value. You will get into trouble a lot of the times. You even block draws like KQs, while not blocking any value hands.

What I would do being so deep is check-raise a narrower range. For example raise JJ, TT, and JTs. Mix this with some bluffs like AQs, 98s with a backdoor flushdraw. Obviously also sometimes call with sets and JT to keep the other player in and have a more balanced range. Playing like this it is very clear what to do on later streets.

**Turn**
If we take the check-raise range we constructed on the flop, we can comfortably continue betting and stacking off with our value hands. The turn does not give us flush draw equity for our bluffs. Maybe continue betting with 98s, and give up with AQs. 98s has the least showdown value. AQs might win against a draw who decides not to bluff.

Now to your actual hand. Despite getting a very good turn, it is getting really awkward. You are playing a massive pot oop and you are unsure where you are at. Frankly, I really don't know what to do here, which is exactly the reason you should try to avoid this spot entirely. Bet-call? Bet-fold? Check-call? Check-fold? I guess I would check call and check fold the river? I am not liking any option. You choose for bet-call, but I don't think the average person is bluffing in this spot all that often. He could have hands like AQs, KQs, 98s for sure. But you showed so much strength it takes a lot of heart to bluff here. He probably wouldn't do this with AJ. I think he is almost always going to have you beat here.

**In short**
So in short with queens here I would probably check call all three streets, except on bad runouts. Value bet the river if button checks turn.

Comment: Yes I agree. I showed a ton of strength but he put me all in anyway. Should have folded the river. My motivation for the check-raise was just because I thought he would c-bet wide,  and i wanted to defend my vulnerable queens. But i should have been more willing to let them go once it was clear i was beat.

Comment: QQvsAA.  Of course!

Comment: 3-ways he might not even c-bet wide. BB cold call ranges usually include a lot of JJ and TT. I would be afraid to c-bet. Besides your queens aren't that vulnerable on such a dry board.

Comment: Always aces, haha. Too bad :(. Sometimes you have to lose chips, but by calling the flop you might lose half your stack.

Comment: Actually I was a little supprised how agressive he played it.  I think i could have had a lot of hands in my range which would beat him, so Im not convinced his shove achieved anything. He should have just kept calling and allow me a chance to tripple barrel.

Comment: I agree, his raise on the turn is probably a little too optimistic. On the other hand aces is a very strong hand, you don't block any draws and have equity against 2 pair.

Answer (score 1):

On that flop you are behind AA, KK, JJ, and TT. It is time to slow down. Do you think button is raising pre with a middle pair?